# Communication link failure error while running a SQL agent job in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We are getting communication link failure error for a direct loading package in SSIS frequently with errors like
1)

> Shared Memory Provider: Timeout error [258]. Code: 0xC004701A and
>   failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202009.

2)

> Shared Memory Provider: Timeout error [258]. Code: 0xC002F210. Failed
>   with the following error: "Communication link failure".  Possible
>   failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set
>   correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
>   correctly.

any suggestions regarding this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check if destination and source connections are set properly. Try to execute package directly from data tools instead of agent job and see error log. Most probably, this is a configuration error (if your SSIS package runs correctly)

Comment: when we directly run the package in SQL Server visual studio it is working fine. Earlier it worked fine through SQL server agent too.

Comment: I have same problem, have you found the solution? can you post it?